# Mandrill/MailChimp Replace Unsubscribe Link

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

Currently using a system to send emails in which templates are created in MailChimp. From the codebase, using mandrill, hit the madrill API to utilize the template and send emails where they need to go.

MailChimp auto creates an Unsubscribe Link. Is it possible to replace this? I've tried using asterisk|UNSUB|asterisk in the template and I can pull in my unsub link but the auto generated unsubscribe is still there.

I want to get rid of the MailChimp auto generated unsub. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`<a href='{{unsub "anyUrlToYouWantToAddForUnsubPurpose.com"}}'> Unsubscribe Here. </a>`  in  your template code .